Connection issue in hibernate
I need to connect my song class with the database using hibernate. But, hibernate is not connecting and excutting the queries. I used several methods and several dependencies of hibernate but still it is not executing.
Song.java
package com.projects.demohibernate;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="Song")
public class Song {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Songname")
    private String Songname;

    @Column(name = "Artist")
    private String Artist;

    public Song(int id, String songname, String artist) {
        this.id = id;
        Songname = songname;
        Artist = artist;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setSongname(String songname) {
        Songname = songname;
    }
    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        Artist = artist;
    }
}


And my main file
Source.java
package com.projects.demohibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Source {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Song.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Song song1 = new Song();
            song1.setId(1);
            song1.setSongname("Cameo");
            song1.setArtist("James Cameo");
            System.out.println("Song saved");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(song1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            sessionFactory.close();

        }
    }
}

My configuration file
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Song</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>


  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

I need to connect my Song class with my MySql database with the help of hibernate.

Try to switch the javax package to jakarta package in Song file. It worked for me and i think it will work for you as well.
Add the dependency in the pom.xml file
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

